# Organise parent and child navigation into global layout

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bulma

Let me just give you a brief introduction to the question, I'm going to be having about 20 pages on my website once a user logs in, I need to organise these pages to use the same header, so I've come to the decision to use a layout as I'm using Laravel framework, it seemed stupid to have the same header spread across the 20 pages, if I wanted to make a change it would be hell.

In Bootstrap, I didn't add any kind of active class to any of the selected pages, it was just a navigation bar, I've recently upgraded to the Bulma framework where it requires an active class on the parent tab to show the child tabs, sort of a parent and sub categorys system going on.

I'm not sure how to handle this in the Layout, I need to add an active class and I also need to choose which sub navigation to show.

I've added my code below, I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can approach this?

The below code is my whole page, including the header (the `<section class="hero is-danger inside-header">`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }} - Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/public/1.0/frontend/css/bulma.css?id={{ time() }}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/public/1.0/frontend/css/override.css?id={{ time() }}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body class="inside">
    <section class="hero is-danger inside-header">
        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="columns is-vcentered">
                    <div class="column is-5">
                        <p class="title header-title">Introducing {{ config('app.name') }}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle">Interacting with others...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-3"></div>
                    <div class="column is-4">
                        <a class="button is-danger is-large is-disabled join-game-button">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Join Game
                        </a> 
                        <a class="button is-success is-large is-disabled users-online-button">
                            <i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;10
                        </a>
                        <br><br>
                        <a class="button is-success is-large is-disabled platform-button">Platform: Closed Beta</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-foot">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="tabs is-boxed">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="is-active">
                            <a href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->username }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax">
                                <i class="fa fa-university"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Business
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Gangs
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://bulma.io/documentation/elements/box/">
                                <i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Community
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/">
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Store
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <nav class="navbar has-shadow">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-tabs">
                <a class="navbar-item is-tab is-active" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/">Home</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/">Profile</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/customize/">Education</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/classes/">Skills</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/modular/">Housing</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/modular/">Security</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container holorp-container-fixed">
        <br>
        <div class="columns is-desktop">
            <div class="column is-8">
                <div class="message is-danger">
                    <div class="message-body">
                        <p>not sure what can even go here...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-4">
                <div class="message is-success">
                    <p class="message-header">Change Log <span class="is-pulled-right"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></p>
                    <div class="message-body">
                        <span class="tag is-dark">26/09/17</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<code>Updates the platform with a fresh design</code><br>
                        <span class="tag is-dark">26/09/17</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<code>Upgraded from Laravel 5.4 to 5.5</code><br>
                        <span class="tag is-dark">26/09/17</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<code>Added core features to the admin panel</code><br>
                        <span class="tag is-dark">26/09/17</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<code>Did something, can't even remember</code><br>
                        <br>
                        <p><a class="modal-button" data-target="#modal-forgotPassword" id="forgot-pw-modal">View all recent changes</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need "the same header" on every page. Laravel comes with [Blade Template Engine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade), it has a set of methods to help us.

Using the template engine, you can create your app template in **resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

using **@yield** you can inform what part is dynamic:

```
<div class="container">
   @yield('content')
</div>
```

To reuse the template in others views, for example using two pages:

The content of file **resources/views/layouts/pages/one.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
 <h1>Page 1</h1>
</div>
@endsection
```

The content of file **resources/views/layouts/pages/two.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
 <h1>Page 2</h1>
</div>
@endsection
```

Using **@yield**, **@extends** and **@section** you can reuse any HTML template in your Laravel Application.

We can create any **@yield** that we need:

```
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
@yield('scripts')
```

And reuse in our pages:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
 <h1>More than one @yield</h1>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" />
    console.log('using Blade Template Engine');
</script>
@endsection
```

There is the **@include** method, that includes the content of another file if you need.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <div class="row">
 <h1>Page 2</h1>
   @include('forms.form2')
 </div>
@endsection
```

**UPDATE**:

Knowing these things above, we can do:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
 <h1>You are in Item B</h1>
<ul>
   <li id="liA">Item A</li>
   <li id="liB">Item B</li>
   <li id="liC">Item C</li>
</ul>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" />
    var d = document.getElementById("liB");
    d.className += " is-active";
</script>
@endsection
```

This will add the CSS class in the element with id "liB", we need to use something to identify the element, I'm using "id" property but you can use anyone, just need to check what JS method to use to get it in "d" variable. You can check this for more information [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

I don't use [Bulma](http://bulma.io/documentation/components/tabs/), but I believe that will do what you want.

Comment: This doesn't help determine what page you're viewing, which defeats the whole objective of this question.

Comment: I put a JS example that adds a CSS class to an element, the point here is: server-side rendering and client-side rendering may help each one, our work is just to put things in correct place.